# How to override Languange_ru.properties using existing hook for JSP?

Tags: liferay, hook

Hi I have a hook for forgot_password.jsp and for other login related portlet.

In my forgot_password.jsp I have a button, of which value is send-password-reset-link .

For this entry there is no Russian translation. So I thought to add hook for Language_ru.properties.

In Liferay-hook.xml I added 
com/dcp/serviceportal/portlets/hook/resources/Language_ru.properties

It didn't worked so with reference to some of the threads in liferay forum I added
content/Language_ru.properties

It also not worked. I also tried by renaming the properties file from Language_ru.properties to Language_ru_RU.properties. But again bad luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help. I found the reason why my Language hook was not working. Actually in my project we already have Language-ext_ru.properties which has high priority than Language_ru_RU.properties and Languange_ru.properties. Thats the reason why I was not able to apply hook for Langauge_ru.properties.

Answer (score 2):

Add to `portlet.xml` the resource bundle

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>My Portlet</portlet-name>
    <portlet-class>com.my.MyPortlet</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>view-jsp</name>
        <value>/html/view.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
    <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </supports>
    <resource-bundle>content/Language</resource-bundle>
    <portlet-info>
        <title>My Portlet</title>
    </portlet-info>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
</portlet>
```

and put `Language_ru.properties` to `src/content/`.

For more details see http://goo.gl/CmMju